# Show and hide node info on mouseover in cytoscape with tippy version 5.x

Tags: javascript, cytoscape, popper.js, tippyjs

I have it set up in this codepen:I have two questions related to this solution using Tippy v4. [related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54547927/show-and-hide-node-info-on-mouseover-in-cytoscape#new-answer?newreg=bd1745b2a138420f9afab5e61d8d8369)

JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
container: document.getElementById("cy"),
style: [{
    selector: "node",
    style: {
      content: "data(id)"
    }
  },
  {
    selector: "edge",
    style: {
      "curve-style": "bezier",
      "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
    }
  }
],
elements: {
  nodes: [{
    data: {
      id: "a"
    }
  }, {
    data: {
      id: "b"
    }
  }],
  edges: [{
    data: {
      id: "ab",
      source: "a",
      target: "b"
    }
  }]
},
layout: {
  name: "grid"
}
}));

function makePopper(ele) {
let ref = ele.popperRef();
tippy(ref, {
  // popperInstance will be available onCreate
  lazy: false,
  onCreate(instance) {
    instance.popperInstance.reference = {
      clientWidth: 10,
      clientHeight: 10,
      getBoundingClientRect() {
        return {
          w: 20, h:20
        };
      },
    };
  },
});
}
cy.ready(function() {
cy.elements().forEach(function(ele) {
  makePopper(ele);
});
});

cy.elements().unbind('mouseover');
cy.elements().bind('mouseover', (event) => event.target.tippy.show());

cy.elements().unbind('mouseout');
cy.elements().bind('mouseout', (event) => event.target.tippy.hide());

});
```

HTML:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-popper@1.0.5/cytoscape-popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@5/dist/tippy-bundle.iife.js"> 
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@5/dist/backdrop.css">  

</head>

<body>
 <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px
}

#cy {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
opacity: 0.5;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

1) Is it possible to make the Tippy follow the node as it is dragged?  I have tried adding the property like this in cy.ready(), tippy.setDefaultProps({followCursor: 'true'}); But I get an error that the tippy.setDefaultProps() is not a function.  I have set this Tippy v4 question up in this codepen:  [setDefaultProps codePen](https://codepen.io/rbogard/pen/jOEyWrL)

```
tippy.setDefaultProps({followCursor: 'true'});
```

2) I cannot get the tippy example to work with Tippy v5.  I get an error, tippy was passed as a plain object which is no longer supported.  I have tried passing a ref object, but I get the same error. I have it v5 set up in this codepen:
[Tippy v5 error](https://codepen.io/rbogard/pen/mdyRPew)  The code shown above is the Tippy v5 code, but the Tippy v4 code is very similar.

Comment: for 1 - try this (v6 - better code + better docs): https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/#follow-cursor